# Li-Ion/Li-Polymer Battery Charger mcp73871-2cci/ml Issue

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, charging, lithium-polymer

Hope someone can help.  I have designed a pcb board based on the [mcp73871-2cci/ml](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP73871-Data-Sheet-20002090E.pdf). No matter what I change there is no current draw and all the indication LED’s remain on. I have seen some example schematics, some have pull down resistor and others do not. I also changed the 10k NTC THERM to a 10k resistor and there is still no change. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: What voltage do you measure on the THERM pin?  Do you have this hooked up to a battery or a battery emulator?  What's the battery voltage?  If ALL the LEDs on the only two possibilities seem to be a temperature fault or a safety timer timeout.  The latter is measured in hours, so probably not the root cause.

Comment: @JohnD  3.50V. across the THERM pin and the battery is at 4.00V I have it hooked up to a battery. But the LEDs only turn on when the charger is connected otherwise nothing turns on.

Comment: 3.5V is above the upper temp trip point.  With 10K you should see 50uA * 10K = 0.5V on the THERM pin.  Are you sure your 10K resistor is 10K?

Comment: Initially, there was a 10K NTC thermistor, I changed this to a general 10k resistor, still getting the same voltage across it. I also noticed on my schematic there was a capacitor in line with the negative terminal of the battery. I made all of these changes and the LED indicated STAT1 and STAT2 are on.

Comment: a picture with more resolution would be really helpful